# Trying to get property of non-object when get value in variable

Tags: php

> trying to get property of non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\sufiapiwork\poetlist.php on line 24

Can you fix it? I don't have any idea what happened.
Here is my code.

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$url="someurl";
$data = json_decode(get_data($url), true);

foreach($data as $val)
{
    echo $val->Name_Hi;
}
```

Comment: `echo $val['Name_Hi'];`

Comment: Hi Vivek, Can you please show the output of $data?.

Comment: @NishantNair : so or show?

Comment: when i echo than output is  Undefined index: Name_Hi

Comment: `$data=json_decode($result,true);` what exaclty does $data contain?. Print it and add in your question.

Comment: show us what you see when you `print_r($data);` - It is clearly an array, but we need to see what it contains.

Comment: @ Nishant Nair  when i print_r the variable $data the output is

Comment: Hi Guys I edit question once again

Comment: :o please, reformat this huge print_r and if you can, show us a minimum data sample this is absolutely unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you would need to firstly specify `$data['Result']` index in your array and then use `$val['Name_Hi']` to view the data.

```
foreach($data['Result'] as $val) {

    if($val['Name_Hi'] !== ''){

     echo $val['Name_Hi'] . '<br>';
  }

}
```

Output:

```
आजिज़
आज़ाद
अब्दुल्ला हाशिमी
अली रहमती
अमानुल्ला
असदुल्ला शाह
फ़कीरा
फ़ज़ल बिन मुहम्मद अमीन
घासीराम
ग़रीब शाह
गुलामनबी हैदराबादी
ग़वासी दकनी
हसनअली शाह
हातिम दकनी
हुसेनी
इब्न निशाती
इसहाक़ बीजापुरी
Jagjeevan Saheb
करीमुद्दीन सरमस्त
महकम दकनी
महमूद दकनी
```

Comment: only person with the idea to visit the URL specified haha. +1

Comment: No worries!      \m/ \m/

Comment: @Kitson88 i thanks brother. you have solve my problem...i am sorry i little bit confused

Comment: @VivekMishra That's cool, just don't forget to accept the answer if your happy.

Comment: @Kitson88 how to convert this data in pagination format

Comment: In what context? limiting the number of results per page?

Comment: @Kitson88 i want to display poet name  on page limit of per page is 10 records. actually i have no idea how to paginate record using api..i am new

Comment: @VivekMishra I'm afraid this is another question in itself. Best thing I could advise here would be to start a new question making sure to explain what you need and what you have tried so far. Make sure to show current code and if possible some form of output.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode($result, true);` make associative array / hash instead of anonymous object. The notation is then `$val['Name_Hi']` to access the property.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are getting from `json_decode` is an array so you have to use `$val['Name_Hi']`.

If you want an object, you have to remove the second parameter from `json_decode`.

---

#### From the doc

The function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) has 4 parameters

- `$json` => the json string to decode
- `$assoc = false` => if true, you will get an array, if false (or not defines) you will get an object
- `$depth = 512` => sets the maximum depth for decoding nested values
- `$options = 0` => additionnal options for the decode function

The only needed parameter is `$json`